# Handle chrome packaged application closing

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-app

Is it possible to run some code before chrome packaged app is closing?

Those methods have not helped:

- `chrome.app.window.current().onClosed`
- `chrome.runtime.onSuspend`
- `window unload event`

For example:

```
chrome.runtime.onSuspend.addListener(function() {
    $.ajax({ url: 'http://isup.me/' });    
});
```

After closing application, I do not see any http requests in web monitoring tool (Fiddler2).

Comment: `chrome.runtime.onSuspend` should be the way. Define "not helped".

Comment: I've extended description.

Comment: You're doing that in the event page, right?

Comment: Just in JS code. I.e. <script> // some code </script>

Comment: I've also tried to do it in background.js file

Comment: What is 'event page'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[When a packaged app is closing](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_lifecycle#lifecycle), its Event page (defined in the background scripts section of the manifest) receives a `chrome.runtime.onSuspend` event. So, your code should be there. But..

This event means it is being unloaded, and only has very little time for [cleanup](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_lifecycle#lifecycle). Quoting:

> Once this event is fired, the app runtime starts the process of closing the app: all events stop firing and JavaScript execution is halted. Any asynchronous operations started while handling this event are not guaranteed to complete. **Keep the clean-up tasks synchronous and simple.**

`$.ajax()` is an asynchronous, and rather slow, operation. Therefore, it has a high probability of failing in a clean-up handler.

In principle, this can be made synchronous, but this is [disabled](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_deprecated) in Chrome Apps. So no, you cannot reliably send a network request when your app is closing.

---

It is possible that [there is a workaround](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=130465) using `onClosed` handlers:

```
chrome.app.window.create('window.html', function(win) {
  win.onClosed.addListener(function() {
    // ...
  });
});
```

This might work, since any asynchronous tasks started from here technically start before `onSuspend` is fired, so an event page should not start unloading. But I haven't tried personally.

Comment: @Alexander I would appreciate if you try the second method and report if it works.

Comment: It should also be mentioned that any processing that the developer wants to upon closing is suspect. Apps should be designed so that they are, to the extent possible, always in a position of not losing any work if they should stop, for whatever reason, such as power failure, closing or crashing of the browser, destruction of the computer, deliberate closing, trashing on the extension window, etc.

Comment: @Marc It's all spelled out on the lifecycle documentation, I think.

Answer (score 0):

I can vouch for the workaround (callback in window.create() that registers a .onClosed listener)... it worked perfectly for me, but all the other documented solutions never worked at all in my tests.